# C# checking if SharePoint list entry already exist .. CAML?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, duplicates, caml, sharepoint-list

I have two identical SharePoint lists.  I'm using C# to loop through one and adding to the other using the SP object model.

Problem is I don't want to add to the other, if there is already a list entry with 3 specific fields that match the from list.

How can do this is in C#? using CAML?

Say my lists are called from and to and the fields are called a,b and c.

Here, I don't want to add a entry to "to", if there is already an entry in to with a,b and c matching my currently from entry.

```
SPList fList = web.GetList("/sites/xxxx/Lists/from"); 
SPList tList = web.GetList("/sites/xxxx/Lab/Lists/to"); 

foreach (SPListItem fListItem in fList.Items)     
{   
   // my caml code here i suspect?
   //SPquery.query = "CAML";
   //SPList<yourlist>.GetItems(SPQuery object) 

   SPListItem tListItem = tList.Items.Add();       
   foreach (SPField field in fList.Fields)      
    {                   
 try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by using SPMetal (LINQ To SharePoint if possible).

```
    MyContext context = new MyContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);

var fItems = from f in context.FromList
        select f;

foreach(FItem fitem in fItems)
{
    var toFoundItems = from t in context.ToList
                where t.Field1 == fitem.Field1 && t.Field2 == fitem.Field2 && t.Field3 == fitem.Field3
                select t;

    if(t.Count > 0)
        continue;
    else
        //Code to add items can use context to do this here also
    }
```

The other way is like you mentioned and use SPQuery.

```
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = string.format("
<Where> 
    <AND>  

        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
            <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Field2' />
                <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Field3' />
                <Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>");

    SPListItemCollection items = tList.GetItems(query);

if(items.Count > 0)
    continue;
else
    //Code to add item
```

I am not at my normal PC so I can't test either of these codes but should give you an idea of how to start, it is unfortunate that SharePoint doesn't allow composite unique keys.

It would be possible to enforce the composite unique key with an event receiver on that list if you want to approach the problem from a different angle.

Comment: Thank you. meant to mention we are on SP2007 and so LINQ is not available I think.

Comment: I've asked a related question. Possible to get a count from an SPD generated SPDatasource with a filter generated CAML using C#? What's the easiest way? thanks.

Comment: Is there some kind of issue using single qoutes inside CAML like this ..I get every single row back on this query when I should only be returning 1 row <Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Archive Date'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-5'/></Value></Geq></Where></Query>

Comment: I don't see an issue with your query (Get all rows where archive date is greater than or equal to 5 days ago)  is it possible archive date is not the value you are expecting?  Is it empty or null?